# Which one is better, iterate and sort data in backend or let the database handle it?

Tags: database, api, database-design, backend

I'm trying to design a database schema for Djabgo rest framework web application.
At some point, I have two choces:

1- Choose a schema in which in one or several apies, I have to get a queryset from database and iterate and order it with python. (For example, I can store some datas in an array-data-typed column, get them from database and sort them with python.)

2- store the data in another table and insert a kind of big number of rows with each insert. This way, I can get the data in my favorite format in much less lines with orm codes.

I tried some basic tests and benchmarking to see which way is faster, and letting database handle more of the job (second way) didn't let me down. But I don't have the means of setting a more real situatuin and here's the question:

Is it still a good idea to let database handle the job when it also has to handle hundreds of requests from other apies and clients each second?
Is database (and orm) usually faster and more reliable than backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, you want to let the database do work when the work is appropriate for the database.  Sorting result sets would be in that category.

Keep in mind:

- The database is running on a server, often on a distributed system and so it has access to more resources.
- Databases are designed to handle large data, so they are not limited by the memory in a single thread.
- When this question comes up, often more data needs to be passed back to the application than is strictly needed.  Consider a problem such as getting the top 10 of something.
- Mixing processing in the application and the database often requires multiple queries and passing data back and forth, which is expensive.

(And there are no doubt other considerations.)

There are some situations where it might be more efficient or convenient to do work in the application.  A common example is formatting result sets for the application -- say turning `1234.56` into `$1,234.56`.  Other examples would be when the application language has capabilities that are not directly in SQL or are hard to implement in SQL.

Comment: Thank you, This was a huge help.